# how to generate a complex query without a param with JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to genaerate a query like below.

```
select * FROM news ORDER BY ptime DESC LIMIT 5
```

I have tried

```
List<News> findAllOrderByPtimeDesc();
```

or

```
List<News> findFirst10AllOrderByPtimeDesc();
```

It always said

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
```

Can I generate a method to implement this query directly?

Comment: can you share the code which produce this error please?

Comment: You should probably use an extra `By` between your statements

Comment: findTop5ByOrderByPtimeDesc

Comment: why would a method signature _alone_ be any use to us? we need to see the logic which goes on inside the said method.

Comment: @Aominè because spring-data-jpa can derive queries from method signatures.

Comment: @JBNizet I see, good to learn something new eh. ;-)